# TypeError: f[s] is not a function for jquery form submission

Tags: jquery, function, submit, typeerror

I'm trying to get a form to submit in a roundabout way, since I need it to append new inputs before it submits. Since putting appends in the actual $(form).submit() function will not gather them for post, I've added an html button to call a submitCheck(), and then submit the actual function.

```
function init() {
  $("#submit").click(submitCheck);
  //and lots of other stuff
}

function submitCheck() {
    //go through fabric canvases, save xml to input.
    for (var i=1; i<probNum; i++) {
        var csvg = gcanvas[i].toSVG();
        $('#output').append("<input type='hidden' name='svg"+probNum+"' value='"+csvg+"'></input>");
    }
    //make sure a topic was selected. If not cancel submission and don't do anything.
    if ($("#topic").val() == '-1') 
    {
        $('#error').html("You must select a valid topic");
    } else {
        //submit the form
        alert('should submit now');
        $("form:first").submit();
    }
}
```

But... it fails, throwing the type error:

```
TypeError: f[s] is not a function
```

I've found no documentation on this particular error. Any ideas?

Comment: There are no `f` and `s` variables in your code snippet. Possibly the error is thrown from some third party script? For instance, I don't know anything about `toSVG()` method. Where is it from?

Comment: The f and s variables are from jquery, as mentioned in the header and tags. toSVG is from fabric.js but doesn't have anything to do with the bug - I included it for completeness and to give a better idea of the function process.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You have some input with `name="submit"` in your form, which overrides the native `form.submit` (programmatically submits the form) method that is being called internally in jQuery. You need to change that to some other name.

See the Additional Notes paragraph in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/submit/#entry-longdesc).

You can also use [DOMLint](http://kangax.github.com/domlint/) to see other possible conflict issues.

Comment: In my case, the `<input` with `id="submit"` was also a problem. I removed the `id="submit"` and it worked.