# TypeError: s [y] is not a function Error

Tags: jquery

I am getting using jQuery 1.8.3

```
TypeError: s [y] is not a function
```

And i searched error,get that issue with form submit. But i am not using form.

What this error say?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168171/typeerror-fs-is-not-a-function-for-jquery-form-submission

Comment: You may also want to load the unminified version of jQuery, so you get actual variable and method names instead of `s[y]`.

Comment: it would be very helpful if we had some code to look at instead of just an obscure error...

Answer (score 2):

If you have some input with name="submit" in your form, which overrides the native form.submit
try to change that to some other name and try again.